# Weird error using preg_match and unicode

Tags: php, regex, unicode

```
if (preg_match('(\p{Nd}{4}/\p{Nd}{2}/\p{Nd}{2}/\p{L}+)', '2010/02/14/this-is-something'))
{
  // do stuff
}
```

The above code works. However this one doesn't.

```
if (preg_match('/\p{Nd}{4}/\p{Nd}{2}/\p{Nd}{2}/\p{L}+/u', '2010/02/14/this-is-something'))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Maybe someone could shed some light as to why the one below doesn't work. This is the error that is being produced:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: preg_match()
>   [function.preg-match]: Unknown
>   modifier '\'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`modifier u`](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) is available from PHP `4.1.0` or greater on Unix and from PHP `4.2.3` on win32.

Also as nvl observed, you are using / as the delimiter and you are not escaping the / present in the regex. So you'lll have to use:

```
/\p{Nd}{4}\/\p{Nd}{2}\/\p{Nd}{2}\/\p{L}+/u
```

To avoid this escaping you can use a different set of delimiters like:

```
#\p{Nd}{4}/\p{Nd}{2}/\p{Nd}{2}/\p{L}+#
```

or

```
@\p{Nd}{4}/\p{Nd}{2}/\p{Nd}{2}/\p{L}+@
```

> As a tip, if your delimiter is present in your regex, its better to choose a different delimiter not found in the regex. This keeps the regex clean and short.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (delimit the regex with ())

```
if (preg_match('#\p{Nd}{4}/\p{Nd}{2}/\p{Nd}{2}/\p{L}+#', '2010/02/14/this-is-something'))
{
   // do stuff
}
```

---

Edited

Answer (score 0):

In the second regex you're using `/` as the regex delimiter, but you're also using it in the regex.  The compiler is trying to interpret this part as a complete regex:

```
/\p{Nd}{4}/
```

It thinks the next character after the second `/` should be a modifier like 'u' or 'm', but it sees a backslash instead, so it throws that cryptic exception.

In the first regex you're using parentheses as regex delimiters; if you wanted to add the `u` modifier, you would put it after the closing paren:

```
'(\p{Nd}{4}/\p{Nd}{2}/\p{Nd}{2}/\p{L}+)u'
```

Although it's legal to use parentheses or other bracketing characters (`{}`, `[]`, `<>`) as regex delimiters, it's not a good idea IMO.  Most people prefer to use one of the less common punctuation characters. For example:

```
'~\p{Nd}{4}/\p{Nd}{2}/\p{Nd}{2}/\p{L}+~u'

'%\p{Nd}{4}/\p{Nd}{2}/\p{Nd}{2}/\p{L}+%u'
```

Of course, you could also escape the slashes in the regex with backslashes, but why bother?